# insert object into database from java

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to do some insertion into my database (SQL Developer) from java.
The information found in my database looks like :

```
create or replace type shop as object (name varchar2(30),price number(10));
```

and a table :

```
create table product (id number, obj shop);
```

now, when trying to insert into my database from my java code, I have an error like ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes.

I think this is because of data that I insert.
I've created a function to insert, that has an id and a string.
The problem , i think , is that string, because I need to insert in my "PRODUCT" table, some "SHOP" values.
But i do not know how to insert "SHOP" values from my java code.
My java code looks like :

```
   public class ShopManager {
     public void create(Integer ID,String prod) throws SQLException {
        Connection con = Database.getConnection();
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into product (id,obj) values (?,?)")) {
            pstmt.setInt(1,ID);
            pstmt.setString(2, product);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }
}
```

And this is how I try to insert :

```
ShopManager man = new ShopManager();
string manager = "shop(\'Name1\',10)";
man.create(1,manager);
//and here i commit
```

So, the fact is , that i do not know how to do not insert a STRING from java instead of a shop object that's in my database.

Comment: You're dealing with a relational DB, why deal with objects ? create a table called `SHOP` that has two columns: `name` and `price` and add a row to the table upon each insertion.

Comment: The only ID i have there is just the product Id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `shop` object constructor as part of the insert statement, but you need both a product ID and shop price as numbers, not a combined string:

```
insert into product (id, obj) values (?, shop(?, ?))
```

... so the String becomes the second argument you need to set, and you need to decide where the other two argument values are coming from. It looks like you should change your function spec to:

```
public void create(Integer prodID, String name, Integer shopID)
```

and then call it as:

```
man.create(1, "Name1", 10);
```

although that assumes 'price' will always be am integer, which is probably unlikely, so the third function argument should probably be a float type (with appropriate set call too).